# I noticed that Xcode produces multiple copies of folders, any suggestion of how to stop this?

Tags: xcode, file-management

```
> ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/.DS_Store
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/.DS_Store
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/AppDelegate.h
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/AppDelegate.m
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
> 12 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/Base.lproj
> 4  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/C2ViewController.h
> 12 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/C2ViewController.m
> 8  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/.DS_Store
> 4  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.h
> 8  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.m
> 4  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
> 8  ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
> 12    ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/.DS_Store
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.h
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.m
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
> 12    ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/.DS_Store
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.h
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/AppDelegate.m
> 4 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
> 12    ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/Base.lproj
> 8 ./ilya14/ios12-14/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/color22/.DS_Store
```

Number of copies of the same folder goes unlimited.
Does anybody familiar with this issue? Can it be fixed?

Comment: I have no clue. You might want to file a bug report at Apple with how you can reproduce it.

Comment: Please document what steps you have taken so we can reproduce.
I have not seen this behavior but would be interested to see the conditions.
I can think of some form of version control or snapshoting that may cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dulio Denis suggestion about version control may cause this is the right one. Having Git turned on, but left poorly managed causes multiple directories produced in Git branching process